# SQL Big Query Trim & lower , data cleaning for unwanted space and lower cap

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-cleaning, trim

... Issue resolve ...

May i check how can i clean my data throughly using big query SQL ?
I have an issue whereby i dont seems to be able to clean my data throughly
Im using

```
WITH d_group AS(
SELECT
    list.group_method AS list_method,
    list.group_method_detailed AS list_detailed
FROM table_a  AS list
),

d_trim AS (
SELECT 
  LOWER(TRIM(list_method)) AS modified_group_method
  LOWER(TRIM(list_detailed)) AS modified_group_method_detailed
  LOWER(TRIM(IFNULL(d_group.list_detailed,d_group.list_method)) AS modified_detailed,
FROM d_group
),

d_detailed AS (
SELECT 
  modified_group_method,
  modified_group_method_detailed,
  modified_detailed
CASE 
  WHEN modified_detailed  LIKE  '%apple'  THEN 'fruits'
  ELSE 'Others'
  END AS fruits_grouping 
FROM d_trim
-- WHERE modified_group_method LIKE '%other' #incorrect here 
WHERE modified_group_method LIKE 'other'
),

d_method AS (
  SELECT 
    modified_group_method,
    modified_group_method_detailed,
    modified_detailed,
CASE 
  WHEN modified_group_method LIKE '%apple'  THEN 'fruits'
  ELSE 'Others'
  END AS fruits_grouping
FROM d_trim
-- WHERE modified_group_method <> '%other' #Incorrect here ..
WHERE modified_group_method <>  'other'

), 

all_table AS (
SELECT 
    d_method.modified_group_method AS group_method ,
    d_method.modified_group_method_detailed AS group_method_detailed,
    d_method.change_detailed AS modified_detailed,
    d_method.payment_mode
  FROM d_method
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    d_detailed.modified_group_method AS group_method ,
    d_detailed.modified_group_method_detailed AS group_method_detailed,
    d_detailed.change_detailed AS modified_detailed,
    d_detailed.payment_mode
  FROM d_detailed
)

SELECT 
  DISTINCT
  list_method, 
  list_method_detailed,
  modified_detailed,
  fruits_grouping
FROM all_table 
ORDER BY
  modified_detailed
```

However there are still "invisible" space which is affecting my CASE WHEN function

My output result is giving me

| group_method | group_detailed | modified_detailed | fruits_grouping |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| other. | apple. | apple. | fruits |
| other. | apple. | apple. | Others |
| apple. | apple. | apple. | fruits |

First & Last line result is correct but 2nd line is wrong . I do want to reflect fruits instead of others

I tried various way , export the data into google sheet and try using functions like
TRIM with LOWER . But still there seems to be "invisible" spacing which is affecting my CASE WHEN statement

Is there anything that im missing out here ?

Comment: lower and trim function really does not interfere with each other. So it's surely nothing to do with that.  Also there is no column called modified_group_method so  question is a bit confusing.  
One thing you might want to check is your LIKE function as its case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks @PratikPatil for your comment .  Ive manage to resolve my issue when i take into consideration that LOWER(TRIM()) does not interference with each other .